# React native "Failed building JavaScript bundle"

Tags: ios, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am trying to run an 8 month old expo React native project and I get this error when trying to run the app.

`hooks/useConversationsSubscription.js: Container is falsy`

The yarn.lock was included so why is it not working anymore? any ideas what could have changed?

I have tried reseting the cache with `expo start -c` but I have to say I'm not familiar with expo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by updating the expo project